# How to create a Fancy Notes-Box in half of the Page along with text

Tags: formatting, boxes, framed

I can draw the following type of Notes-Box:

[image]

Can someone please suggest me how to draw this type of Notes-Box:

[image]

The second one is different from the first one in 2 ways:

- We can add text below the picture (In the first one, picture occupies the left frame completely)
- The second box does not cover the entire space. We can write text on Left side as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `minipage` inside a `\fcolorbox`; the `wrapfigure` environment from the [`wrapfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package can be used to let the text wrap around the box; inside the `minipage`, the positioning for the image and the title can be achieved using, for example, `\parbox`es. In the following example I defined a new environment `mybox` with the help of the `environ` package; the mandatory argument is used for the title of the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[verbose]{wrapfig}
\usepackage{bclogo}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewEnviron{mybox}[1]
  {\wrapfigure{r}{.5\textwidth}
  \setlength\fboxrule{1.5pt}
  \fcolorbox{blue!70}{white}{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
  \parbox[t][1cm][t]{1cm}{\bccrayon}%
  \parbox[t][1cm][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-1cm\relax}{\bfseries#1}
  \BODY
  \end{minipage}}%
\endwrapfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{The Title}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{mybox}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since the environment uses the `wrapfig` package, the  idiosyncrasies of `wrapfig` apply here too (refer to the package documentation for details).